# How to run nunit test in 64bit on MacOSX?

Tags: .net, macos, mono, 64-bit

I have an assembly that needs to be run in 64bit process, but I cannot make it work in nunit runner.

I created a test code, very simple, just print out the pointer size in main function and in a nunit test function:

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace PtrSize
{
    class MainClass
    {
        [Test]
        public static void Test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("IntPtr.Size                : {0}", IntPtr.Size);
            Console.WriteLine ("Environment.Is64BitProcess : {0}", Environment.Is64BitProcess);
        }

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("IntPtr.Size                : {0}", IntPtr.Size);
            Console.WriteLine ("Environment.Is64BitProcess : {0}", Environment.Is64BitProcess);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I did the following tests:

first I confirmed the mono is 64bit built

```
Build-Agent-Mac-01s-iMac:Debug BA-Mac-01$ ~/sandbox/mono64/bin/mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 3.10.0 (tarball Thu Jan  8 09:23:28 CET 2015)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           normal
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notification:  kqueue
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    GC:            sgen
```

Then I use this mono to run my test program, and it is in 64bit process:

```
Build-Agent-Mac-01s-iMac:Debug BA-Mac-01$ ~/sandbox/mono64/bin/mono PtrSize.exe
IntPtr.Size                : 8
Environment.Is64BitProcess : True
```

Then I use nunit test runner to run it, and it is always in 32bit mode, I also tried the nunit-console-x86.exe, but still doesn't help.

```
Build-Agent-Mac-01s-iMac:Debug BA-Mac-01$ ~/sandbox/mono64/bin/mono ~/Downloads/NUnit-2.6.4/bin/nunit-console.exe PtrSize.exe
NUnit-Console version 2.6.4.14350
Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Charlie Poole.
Copyright (C) 2002-2004 James W. Newkirk, Michael C. Two, Alexei A. Vorontsov.
Copyright (C) 2000-2002 Philip Craig.
All Rights Reserved.

Runtime Environment - 
   OS Version: Unix 14.5.0.0
  CLR Version: 2.0.50727.1433 ( Mono 3.5 ( 3.10.0 (tarball Thu Jan  8 09:23:28 CET 2015) ) )

ProcessModel: Default    DomainUsage: Single
Execution Runtime: mono-3.5
.IntPtr.Size                : 4
Environment.Is64BitProcess : False

Tests run: 1, Errors: 0, Failures: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Time: 0.0132951 seconds
  Not run: 0, Invalid: 0, Ignored: 0, Skipped: 0
```

any body has idea on this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Mono 4.2.1, the installer includes a 64-bit version of mono. Unfortunately, the nunit-console command still runs as 32-bit.

To run nunit-console as 64-bit, you still need to use the mono64 command:

```
mono64 /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/4.5/nunit-console.exe <path to dll>
```